# respond_to pdf in Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, prawn

I have an `index` controller action which responds to the `pdf` format which looks something like

```
class ProposalsController < ApplicationController
  respond_to :pdf, :html
  def index
    @proposals = Proposal.all

    respond_with @proposals do |format|
      format.html
      format.pdf
    end
  end
end
```

`Proposal` has a `to_pdf` method which creates `Prawn::Document`. How can I loop over each of the propsals, grab it's PDF, append it to a newly created PDF, and then render that in the browser via `respond_with`?

Comment: Check out http://railscasts.com/episodes/78-generating-pdf-documents

Comment: I'm trying to solve the same problem and I want to keep my views under the same pattern that Rails provides where you have your template for each action and so forth. Meaning I don't like using `to_json` or `to_pdf` because it's harder to maintain. I found this: https://github.com/lloeki/tilt-pdf

Answer (score -3):

One can use rails API to create a personalized renderer. In fact, the book  Crafting Rails 4 Applications by José Valim show you how to create personalized PDF renderer in the first chapter.

Comment: if you think the pointed book contains the response, you could extract sample that would fix it. Also linking the book directly to a shop that sells the book(like amazon)